# Why is my authorization fallback policy overriding AllowAnonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, authorization

I added a fallback policy to my asp.net core application because I wanted to require a specific role as the fallback instead of just blanket authorization.

However, now pages that have the AllowAnonymous attribute are using my fallback policy, which seems to directly contradict documentation. Microsoft docs say that the fallback policy is for pages without any authorize or AllowAnonymous attribute.

> For example, Razor Pages, controllers, or action methods with
> `[AllowAnonymous]` or `[Authorize(PolicyName="MyPolicy")]` use the applied
> authentication attribute rather than the fallback authentication
> policy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I'm wondering if perhaps my configuration in Startup is wrong, but searching I've found nothing similar to my issue.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<MySharedService>();
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    });
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("IsSystemAdmin", policy => policy.RequireRole("SystemAdmin"));
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.GetPolicy("IsSystemAdmin");
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because I was adding a "static" page for the privacy policy, I unintentionally removed the line
`@model PrivacyPolicyModel` from PrivacyPolicy.cshtml.

Therefore the page model at PrivacyPolicy.cshtml.cs was skipped entirely, and any `Authorize` or `AllowAnonymous` attribute was not applied.

One of those bugs I can't believe I wasted so many hours on... Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Got the same issue but I don't understand your answer, the authorize attribute isn't applicable to a model right? So how does referencing a model again with `@model PrivacyPolicyModel` solve your issue?

Comment: In Razor you do apply authorize attributes to the page model (eg. your Index page consists of an Index.cshtml view and an Index.cshtml.cs page model)

Comment: I apply the authorize attribute to the controller not to a model

Comment: Razor Pages shares much with MVC but has some different conventions around page models vs controllers. My code won't be directly applicable to an MVC project.